# HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found on Accelerator Apache Traffic Server

Tags: proxy, apache-traffic-server

I have a problem I'm running an Apache Traffic Server but the problem is that amount and all well but to run a headline like this

```
GET /index/Page?aspxerrorpath=/aspa.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com
```

Executing this request to the server returns 404 not found me on accelerator (ATS)

But the strange thing is that there are proxies internet so that sending http request that I return a 200 response request Ok but my server is not.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add a remap rule to your remap.config? It would look something in the line of

map http://myhost.com  http://origin-for.myhost.com